# How to store PageObject content when doing UI testing with selenium in Java?

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects

I am currently working on UI testing using the Page Object design model. Currently, I am using a hashmap in each of my pages to store content.

The reason why I am using a map is so that whenever I have many fields to fill I use a fillData (Map data) method to match keys.

For instance, my page object would have:

```
Map<String, WebElement> content = new HashMap();

    content.put("backgroundColor", WebElement a);
    content.put("fontColor", WebElement b);
    content.put("linksColor", WebElement c);
    content.put("actionBarActiveColor", WebElement d);
    content.put("activeColor", WebElement e);

public void fillDataFields(Map<String, String> data){

        data.forEach( (k,v) -> {
            content.get(k).setValue(v);
        });
    }
```

and my page test would have:

```
generalAppearanceFieldsData = new HashMap();

        generalAppearanceFieldsData.put("backgroundColor", BLUE_HEX);
        generalAppearanceFieldsData.put("fontColor", ORANGE_HEX);
        generalAppearanceFieldsData.put("linksColor", PURPLE_HEX);
        generalAppearanceFieldsData.put("actionBarColor", RED_HEX);
        generalAppearanceFieldsData.put("actionBarActiveColor", ORANGE_HEX);
        generalAppearanceFieldsData.put("activeColor", GREEN_HEX);
```

And my test would call

```
brandingPage.fillDataFields(generalAppearanceFieldsData);
```

The issue I have with this is that string keys are hard to maintain and to verify since I could call a key that points to nowhere. I'm not sure if maps is the right approach to store page content. Is there a better way to do it with Java?

Answer (score 3):

PageObjects should be used to insulate the test code from the inner workings of the page.  You may want to consider adding methods to your page object that correspond to actions and/or setters, and call them from your test.

The PageObject knows how to do things on the page.
The Test class interacts with the PageObject asking it to do things to the page, and then asserts that things happened as expected.

For example:

```
public class Test {
    private final String BLUE_HEX="0000FF";
    private final String RED_HEX="FF0000";
    private WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        PageObject page = new PageObject(driver);
        page.setBackgroundColor(BLUE_HEX);
        page.setActionBarColor(RED_HEX);
        // do stuff
        assertTrue(page.getSomeValue());
    }
}

public class PageObject {
    private WebDriver driver;

    public PageObject( WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
    private void setText(String id, String val) {
        driver.findElement(By.id(id)).sendKeys(val);
    }
    public void setBackgroundColor(String hex) {
        setText("backgroundColor", hex);
    }
    public void setActionBarColor(String hex) {
        setText("actionBarColor", hex);
    }
    public boolean getSomeValue() {
        // Do some checks on the values etc
        return true;
    }
}
```